# How to get json from Secured API

Tags: c#, authentication, xamarin, oauth-2.0, token

I did an api, for the exemple i will call it: https://testapp.azurewebsites.net.

I did the Authentication / Authorization in Azure for google Facebook and Miscrosoft account.

Then i want to consume it in xamarin for my Android/iOS app, so i did the login button etc but when I'm authentify i can't get the json of my api URL: "https://testapp.azurewebsites.net/api/Test/allCoordinates".

It work's perfectly in my browser and in postman... This is my code in C#:

```
var requestCoord = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri(URL),null , e.Account);
var responseCoord = await requestCoord.GetResponseAsync(); //it works for google userinfo but not for my Api...
string coordJson = await responseCoord.GetResponseTextAsync();
var mapTest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CustomPin>>(coordJson);
```

In Postman it works and i can see this code for C# from postman:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://testapp.azurewebsites.net/api/Test/allCoordinates?access_token=ya29.a0AfH6SMCEGy4tP_zngNEhAcpf31d3O_ZYl7NE9QJjbKrW0KPh-dC7PjNmz-KOCbkySRtuwDJdg2ckhiTaTdIEsONxVhFhK3NpnUk9iITyCB1BnwpWJwNEEivxg0pL93UPP9r4UYf1dHEiTVd63eydfV7HoKlxExMFtS8");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("User-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36");
request.AddHeader("Cookie", "ARRAffinity=d2e047f134af60dd8e0802593ad5206002e99e56a6231fee0e85747cfa96ea6f; AppServiceAuthSession=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");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

But how to find the cookie data in Xamarin ? and call this url ?

If you have any idea to make this Http Get from protected webapi i will help me so much !!!

Thanks a lot

If you need more precision let me know;)

Comment: Instead of JSON, what do you receive from API?

Comment: what happens when you make the request?  What response code do you get?

Comment: It looks like GetResponseText wraps object to string, so try deserialize to `string` first and then to `List<CustomPin>`

Comment: I get the answer Unauthorised 401 that the problem after it should work to get the json

Comment: not sure is 401 but for responseCoord i got System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized

Comment: For information i use this to get user info and token: https://github.com/CuriousDrive/PublicProjects/tree/master/OAuthNativeFlow and https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator?tabs=android

Comment: Do you want to get the login user's Account and Token from Json? If so, you can `Google:Authenticate users through Google with Xamarin.Auth`

Comment: Not really i want to get the json from my url i allready got the token from google, i just want to be Authorized to use my web application... but it doesn't work, i don't know where i did wrong